# Unable to change text of SPAN tag inside H3 tag that has other text that shouldn't change with jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, html

My goal is that when the user clicks on the `<div class="title">`, the text within the `<span>` inside the containing `<h3>` will change and when the click again it will go back to its previous value.

```
<div class="title">
    <h3>Text The Doesn't Change <span>Text That Changes</span></h3>
</div>
```

However when I click on the div, the text changes once and then stops no matter how many times I click.

If I remove the text before the span from the code:

```
<div class="title">
    <h3><span>Text That Changes</span></h3>
</div>
```

Then it works fine however I need that text to be present for my specific application.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('div.title').click(function(){
    $(this).children('h3').children('span').text($(this).text() == '-' ? '+' : '-');;
});
```

Here is a link to the page to see what I am: [Demo](http://proofs.mm4solutions.com/otis-warren/website/portfolio.php)

Comment: Upvotes shall be carry more carefully, just saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this condition you are accessing the wrong element (`div.title`):

```
$(this).text() == '-' ? '+' : '-'
```

This should be:

```
$('h3 > span', this).text() === '-' ? '+' : '-'
```

Everything all together can be reduced to:

```
$('div.title').click(function(){
  var $span = $('h3 > span', this);
  $span.text($span.text() === '-' ? '+' : '-');
});
```

​

Answer (score 2):

Replace `.children(...)` with `.find(...)` -- in your first code block, the `<span>` is actually a direct child of the text node, not of the `<h3>`. Using `.find` will drill down as far as needed to locate the `<span>`.

**UPDATE**

Your use of `this` inside the `.text()` method isn't pointing to what you think it is. Try using a callback function instead:

```
$('div.title').click(function(){
    $(this).find('span').text(function(i,t) {
        return (t=='-') ? '+' : '-';
    });
});​
```

Comment: Code now looks like this `$(this).find('span').text($(this).text() == '-' ? '+' : '-');;` but this doesn't work.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do inside the `.text()` method.

Comment: If you look at the demo site, I want it so when you click on the title, the + changes to a - and when you click again, it changes back to a +. The code works fine if there is no other text inside the `<h3>` but as soon as the it text there it stops working.

Comment: In the future, please post just the relevant HTML code in your question instead of directing us to an entire external website which may or may not exist in the future.